# How to display a message from a property file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, properties, popup

I am tried to display a message in java script using alert. It works

```
alert("User details saved successfully");
```

But, I need to display a custom message from a property file via the alert()

Comment: This will depend on what framework you use. In struts could be `<bean:message key="mykey" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged jsp in your problem, you can use a properties file to store all the messages and fetch the message from properties file and put it in the alert statement in javascript like this:

```
alert("<%=yourMessageToBeDisplayed %>");
```

Hope it helps!!